# How to forward X-Forwarded-For for HAP Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, load-balancing, haproxy

I have to use AWS Load Balancer to forward requests to ha-proxy, which load-balances docker containers.

I also need to redirect non-http requests to https.

AWS includes the X-Forwarded-For in its requests to haproxy, but haproxy does not forward X-Forwarded. How do I configure haproxy to forward that header.

I'm using https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-clusterproxy

Eventually I want to get rid of AWS Load Balancer but at present I need to live with it.

Thank you for any ideas!

**EDIT**
Here is what HA Proxy forwards to the web containers:

```
headers { host: 'idelog.me', 
Apr 10 22:30:47 Web_XMPP 3dec26a7-0440-4569-a945-1a7cfa5a9d11:    cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3AwXyBf3CCQQIl10cQPaxRyb_xe-ExbGkY.Xjy9vKCTaLZJ3MQLfxG2PrAWVKJC%2F9hToKvj8Ue74gk; AWSELB=5D3B1B0B1857AD2EE7B7A30BE969AF569B1E08E8E3952851007566E67148E417431500E40BE8450431DBBBC243214A643166CD10E6A4FC839D82B6EB5EC83338C7C88E58FF; _ga=GA1.2.455486669.1425248270; _gat=1', 
Apr 10 22:30:47 Web_XMPP 3dec26a7-0440-4569-a945-1a7cfa5a9d11:    'cache-control': 'max-age=0', 
Apr 10 22:30:47 Web_XMPP 3dec26a7-0440-4569-a945-1a7cfa5a9d11:    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36', 
Apr 10 22:30:47 Web_XMPP 3dec26a7-0440-4569-a945-1a7cfa5a9d11:    referer: 'http://idelog.me/', 
Apr 10 22:30:47 Web_XMPP 3dec26a7-0440-4569-a945-1a7cfa5a9d11:    'x-forwarded-for': '73.162.39.215, 172.31.13.227', 
Apr 10 22:30:47 Web_XMPP 3dec26a7-0440-4569-a945-1a7cfa5a9d11:    'x-forwarded-proto': 'http' }
```

You can see that x-forward-for is concatenated, but x-forwarded-proto only contains the value of the request between AWS and HA Proxy, which is always http not https.

How do I tell HA Proxy to relay the AWS value of x-forwarded-proto to my web containers?

Comment: Maybe the following serverfault answer points you in the right direction?  http://serverfault.com/a/428822/274332

Comment: Thx, I did see that but I don't really understand how to apply it to my case.

Comment: What do you mean, HAProxy does not forward that header?  It does forward that header, unchanged, unless you configured `option forwardfor` or have something in your config that removes it.

Comment: I clarified this in the question. `x-forward-for` is fine. It is `x-forwarded-proto` that does not get forwarded by HA Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is - don't try to chain load balancers, it's stupid.